# How to send initial data using express-sse?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-sent-events

Im using express-sse package (https://github.com/dpskvn/express-sse) and I wonder how can I send initial data. I am sending notifications when products have changed for example and I also want to send all the notifications as initial data.
I cannot do it where I initialize sse, as I need the user id which I have a middleware for used inside the routes.

**sse/index.js**

```
const SSE = require("express-sse");
const sse = new SSE(["test data"]); //here I cannot get data from my db as i dont have a userId
module.exports = sse;
```

I have 2 routes now. 1 is for the stream:

```
app.use(router.get('/notifications_stream', requireAuth, sse.init);
```

Can I either add a route handler to that route in which I can send all my notifications fetched from db?

```
app.use(router.get('/notifications_stream', requireAuth, sse.init, (req, res)=> {
sse.send("new daa"")
});
```

doesnt do anything of course. So I thought maybe add a 2nd route to handle that:

```
app.use(router.get('/notifications', requireAuth, ()=> sse.send("new data")));
```

that also doesnt work and I dont thing having 2 routes just to get initial data is the way to do it.

How do I do it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

sse.routes.js (file)

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const sse = require('../../../sse/index');
router.get("/stream",sse.init);
module.exports = router;
```

In Main File where you want to trigger:

```
const sse = require('../../../sse/index');
sse.send("order placed", `provider-${provider.provider_id}`);
```

And in Client side:

```
var es = new EventSource('/stream');
es.onmessage = function (event) {
  ...
};
es.addEventListener(provider-${provider.provider_id}, function (event) {
  ...
});
```